# DataGrid not expanding to hold more items when its datasource increases

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework, datasource

I have a datagrid in .net compact framework C# and I set its datasource to a list, my problem is when the list size increases the grid does nota dd the new additions, I have to recreate the grid by exiting the form and going back into it to see the new entries. The number of visible rows remains the same, so for example if I went from 10 to 20 entries in the list the datagrid still only shows 10 visible rows, if I exit and re-enter the form the same list ends up giving the datagrid all 20 visible rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way of actually doing this and I ended up repopulating the database manually every time a cahnge occured then refreshing it to make sure the changes became visible.

Comment: Accepting your own answer is fine, but I think it would be helpful to show a snippet of code to show what you actually did to make this work (like re-assigning the `DataSource`, as I expect you did).

Comment: I was thinking of posting some code but literally all I did was resassign the datasource and call refresh() on the datagird control, so it's not really enough to demonstrate anything.

Comment: Right, but you never mentioned re-assigning the `DataSource`, or specifically mentioned that you're calling `Refresh()` on the `DataGridView`. It would be helpful, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Your list needs to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. One way to do this is to use [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). When you bind to an object that supports `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the grid will update when records are added or deleted.

If grid cells need to update when properties on the object change, then your object needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.